# what's the drawback of using same AWS account in different environments with different VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services

What are the drawbacks of deploying 3 environments (DEV, QA, and Production) under the same AWS account, in different VPC IP tables.

To me it makes sense, if the same team will need to manage 3 different environments.

I've heard people saying that one should use separate accounts for development and production, but does that mean to use completely different environments and that they should have different console login links?

Please advise. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

You can make both ideas work (single account with multiple environments, or multiple accounts with one environment per account) and both have advantages and disadvantages.

If you run multiple environments in the same account:

- your AWS account limits are more easily reached
- a runaway dev script could impact production's ability to scale up
- loss of credentials endangers all of your environments
- developers could accidentally damage production

I think it's also simpler to separate production costs from other costs if you use multiple accounts and consolidated billing.

Setting up cross-account access is simple, if you need it.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, it is recommended to separate the production environment from the rest. For this, you can create a separate AWS account to deployment. The main reason for this is the isolation of the production account from the rest so that both for security as well as more managed control over it.

The problem in having one AWS account for multiple stages (Dev, QA, and Production) is that it is difficult to completely isolate environments only using IAM permissions. Even if its the same team, separating production account from the rest allow them to build confidence in using the other accounts(Dev and QA) without any hesitation. This also reduces the production issues happening by mistakes (Specially when using many AWS services for the application).

To centralize the billing and reduce the management complexities of multiple AWS accounts, you can use [AWS organizations](https://aws.amazon.com/organizations/).

Comment: Thanks. Can you help define "separate AWS account"? Does it mean different IAM user but in the same console login link? Please help me clarify this concept.

Comment: Separate AWS account means, not a different IAM user. I refer to a completely new AWS account with a different root.

Answer (score 0):

It's not separate AWS accounts but organizations.
Please read here https://aws.amazon.com/organizations/ .
Yes, each org will have its own console login link.

Using different VPC in same, for separate dev/qa/prod envs, you need to deal with different names for S3 buckets and DynamoDb tables as these doesn't support VPC segregation.

[Bonus]: One org costs around $100 per month :)

Comment: I just found https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_common-scenarios_aws-accounts-example.html for separate development and production account. But if our username is our my own name (john), does it mean I have 2 accounts: johndev, and johnprod accounts?

Comment: According to link you shared, there will be only one user for you i.e. john in dev account, but this user will also have access to resources in prod account granted through IAM roles created in prod account. This is called Cross-Account-Access explained here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html . You can also take a little inspiration from https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/aws-building-a-secure-cross-account-continuous-delivery-pipeline/ . Don't forget to mark correct-answer if at all it helped you :)